# would a div grow to the size of the appended div

Tags: css

I start of with a empty div(parent). and append a div to it which is set the width & height using the css method in jquery. but the parent div doesn't grow(i checked in the inspect of firebug console in chrome). Do I have to compute the the width + margin of the appended and set the dimenstion of the parent div

and a supplement would what happens to the when you set the parent width and height does it make the child width and height same...I would like to how the appended div setting height affect the children/parent...if there is some link which would explain this..

how would the width behave with reference to relative,absolute positioning and inheriting property

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example in jsfiddle or something.

Comment: If the parent `div` already has a fixed size (i.e. its sides are not `auto`), it will not grow no matter what you put in it.

Answer (score 1):

The **height** of parent div would change when the height of child div is changed.

**But** you'll have to manipulate the **width** of parent div when you change the width of child div.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ4jK/).

---

Relative or absolute positioning would change the Positioning but not the height or width: [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ4jK/1/)

But if you change the position of child div parent div would not move with it: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ4jK/2/)